# How to ensure the data send successfully with AsyncTask function

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have some problems with asynctask...

i use asynctask to send some URL(*.aspx and paramters) to my server and insert some data.
my problem is how to ensure that the data insert successfully in the server. and then, if it's can insert on my server i will update my database on phone that the data send successfully

this is my URL :

```
    vURL = Routines.URL_SEND_SJ +"?sjnumber=SJ-" + Routines.getSJNumber(vContext) +
                                 "&orgid=" + Routines.getOrgId(vContext) +
                                 "&deviceid="  + Routines.getImei(vContext) +
                                 "&savedate=" + vDate +
                                 "&savetime=" + vTime +
                                 "&status=" + vStatusSJNumber +
                                 "&latitude=" + vLatitude + 
                                 "&longitude=" + vLongitude +
                                 "&phonetype=" + vPhoneType +
                                 "&km=" + vKM;
```

AsyncTask class to send the URL via ASPX class

public class ASPX {

```
public static String submitASPXText(String vURL){       
    String vASPXText="";
    HttpClient vHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet vHttpGet = new HttpGet(vURL);
    try{
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        vASPXText = vHttpClient.execute(vHttpGet, responseHandler);
        vASPXText = vASPXText.replace("<span id=\"Label1\">~", "");
        vASPXText = vASPXText.replace("`</span>", Routines.SEND); 
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return vASPXText;
}



private class LocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... vURL) {
        String vASPXText = ASPX.submitASPXText(vURL[0]);
        return vASPXText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String vASPXResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(vASPXResult);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "insert sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the server return a JSON message and then have your app look at the message to see if the data was saved. For example if the insert was successful return ...

```
{
    "returnCode": 0,
    "returnMessage": "Data saved!"
}
```

And if there was an error return

```
{
    "returnCode": 1,
    "returnMessage": "Database Error! Data was not saved!"
}
```

On Android you can use the built in [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to read the JSON message. For example ...

```
JSONObject object = JSONObject(json);
int returnCode = object.getInt("returnCode");
if (returnCode == 0){
    //Data was saved
} else {
    //Data was saved
}
```